# applicationpool identity giving too much access to my web resources

Tags: permissions, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a new windows 2008 R2 configuration and I just published a web site to it.  I set it to an application pool that uses this identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity and played around with the NTFS permissions giving IIS_IUSRS read access, and it still let the web site create files.  So I tried removing even their read access, and they can still open pages on the site.

What am I missing here?  How can I lock the permissions down in windows 2008 (IIS 7.5) to only allow users to write to specific folders and only read specific folders?

I really don't want to have to create a local account and give my app pool that account to use...

Answer (score 1):

There is never any need to be granting the `IIS_IUSRS` group permissions to your public facing web folders. You should be granting rights to the identity that the site is running under, in this case `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

I suspect the problem here is that the `Users` group has write access to these folders. An `ApplicationPoolIdentity` account is always a member of the `Users` group.

Strip back the permissions on your web folders to just `SYSTEM` and `Administrators` then set the requisite permissions needed for your site to the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` account.

To set permissions your can use `ICACLS.EXE` or the GUI. For example, I have the Nerd Dinner MVC site installed on my machine:

```
`ICACLS c:\NerdDinner /grant "IIS AppPool\NerdDinner":(CI)(OI)(R)
```

Via explorer:

[image]

[image]

You won't be able to browse the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` using the GUI or user manager because it's a synthetic account.